# Client receives "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" when doing concurrent calls to WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf, iis-7, .net-4.0, socketexception

I have a `WCF` service (IIS 7, .NET 4, Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise) which is being queried by a web client (written in Java). However, when more than one requests are sent concurrently to the WCF service, the client receives a `"java.net.SocketException: Connection reset"`. I have browsed a lot of the threads and tried to adjust the configuration of my WCF service but the issue is still not fixed. Below are some more details:

web.config (of WCF service):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Alpha.BetaBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <!-- below is for huge files-->
          <!-- dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" / -->

        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="BetaEndpointBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="Alpha.Beta" behaviorConfiguration="Alpha.BetaBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" kind="webHttpEndpoint" behaviorConfiguration="BetaEndpointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Alpha.IBeta">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true">
      <messageLogging
           logEntireMessage="true"
           logMalformedMessages="true"
           logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
           logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
           maxMessagesToLog="3000"
       />
    </diagnostics>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true" >
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="myUserTraceSource" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml"
           type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bin\RequestLogs\Traces.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

WCF Service Behavior:
*Edit: As per the suggestion in the comment below, `ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` has been added in the ServiceBehavior (but I still get the same error)

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

I have also noticed that when, for example, I send two concurrent requests from the web client (e.g. querying the WCF service concurrently from 2 different tabs of Firefox), one of them will return correct results but the other will yield the `SocketException` error. If I then rerun the query which returned the `SocketException` error by itself, it will work correctly.

I have also enabled `WCF Tracing` (new to this), and I see the following Exception Message:

```
The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportReplyChannelAcceptor+TransportReplyChannel, cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted.
```

..with the following stack trace:

```
System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfAborted()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueueChannel`1.EndDequeue(IAsyncResult result, TDisposable&amp; item)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReplyChannel.EndTryReceiveRequest(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext&amp; context)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ReplyChannelBinder.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext&amp; requestContext)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext&amp; requestContext)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OnAsyncReceiveComplete(IAsyncResult result)
System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)
System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.Shutdown(Func`1 pendingExceptionGenerator)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueueChannel`1.OnClosing()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Abort()
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ListenerHandler.AbortChannels()
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ListenerHandler.OnAbort()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Abort()
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnAbort()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Abort()
System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnAbort()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Abort()
System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.Abort()
System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.Stop(Boolean immediate)
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.StopRegisteredObjects(Boolean immediate)
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownWorkItemCallback(Object state)
System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Finally, on the server side, it appears that each time this occurs a Visual Studio popup appears saying that `"An unhandled .NET Microsoft framework exception occurred in w3wp.exe [1248]"` (I have Visual studio open testing my code)

Can anyone help me shed some light into this? Could it be that the WCF service is properly configured but some fine-tuning needs to happen from the Java web-client?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Default concurrency mode for WCF is single.  You might try setting it to multiple - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.concurrencymode.aspx

Comment: @Tim just changed that, same error.